# Erro de Declaração

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema na declaração de uma DIV, como estou aprendendo sozinho, gostaria de uma ajuda com isso. 
 Quando declaro a DIV nesse jeito consigo colocar as imagens lado a lado, mas ai não consigo inserir os textos sem quebra de linha.

```
<section id="times">
        <h2>TIMES</h2>
        <p> Temos para você os mais variados times que você pode apostar e escolher para sua mitada ou ganho ainda mais de cartolas.</p>
        <div>
       <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola">
               <p>Time do Editor
               <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
               <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
           </div>

           <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola">
               <p>Time do Editor
           </div>

           <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola">
               <p>Time do Editor

           </div>

            <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola">
               <p>Time do Editor
           </div>                       

           <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola">
               <p>Time do Editor
           </div>   
            </div>
        </section>
```

E no CSS coloquei desse modo:

```
#times{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: #000000;

}


#times p{
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    max-width: 1000px;

}

div{
        display:flex;
        text-align: top; 
        bottom: auto;


}

div.figure {
  display: table;
  padding:  10px 10px    
}
div.figure p + p {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
  padding: -20px -20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-style:oblique;

}

figcaption p {
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Dica 1: Fecha as *tags* com `</p>`; Dica 2: Utilize `min-width: 300px` na classe `figure`.

Comment: Resolvido, Obrigado!

Comment: Italo, é sempre bom finalizar a pergunta marcando ✓ na resposta que resolveu seu problema. Se a resposta ainda tem algum problema, pode usar o campo de comentários para fazer questionamentos, mas nunca deixe as suas perguntas sem resolução. Isso não é o foco da comunidade. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Além de faltar fechar as tags `<p>`, você pode colocar `white-space: nowrap;` na declaração `div.figure p + p` para evitar quebra de linha:

```
div.figure p + p {
   display: table-caption;
   caption-side: top;
   padding: -20px -20px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family:inherit;
   font-style:oblique;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Veja:**

```css
#times{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: justify;
   padding: 20px 20px;
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   color: #000000;
}

#times p{
   margin-bottom: 2.5em;
   max-width: 1000px;
}

div{
   display:flex;
   text-align: top; 
   bottom: auto;
}

div.figure {
   display: table;
   padding:  10px 10px;
}

div.figure p + p {
   display: table-caption;
   caption-side: top;
   padding: -20px -20px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family:inherit;
   font-style:oblique;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

figcaption p {
   -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="times">
   <h2>TIMES</h2>
      <p> Temos para você os mais variados times que você pode apostar e escolher para sua mitada ou ganho ainda mais de cartolas.</p>
   <div>
      <div class="figure">
         <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
         <p>Time do Editor</p>
         <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
         <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
      </div>

      <div class="figure">
         <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
         <p>Time do Editor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="figure">
         <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
         <p>Time do Editor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="figure">
         <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
         <p>Time do Editor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="figure">
         <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
         <p>Time do Editor</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```